# Azure WebJob can't connect to Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-webjobs

I have a console app running a continuous WebJob. The web app where the Job lives in can successfully connect to an Azure Hosted SQL Database, but the WebJob using Entity Framework Core can't. It always times out with

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RetryLimitExceededException : 
Maximum number of retries (6) exceeded while executing database operation with 'SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy'. See inner exception for the most recent failure. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Database 'xxx' on server 'yyy' is not currently available. Please retry the connection later.
```

I logged the Conn String and it seems correct. Also the exception stating database 'xxx' and server 'yyy' indicate that the conn string is correct.

Am I missing any setting here?

Answer (score 0):

> "Database  on server  is not currently available. Please retry the connection later."

There are two types of Azure SQL Database connectivity issues: transient errors and persistent errors. According to your error message, it seems to  belong to transient errors.  Database reconfiguration and database  resource limits all could cause this error. In this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-troubleshoot-common-connection-issues), we could know some steps to resolve transient connectivity issues.

Besides, you could check your connection string, firewall settings, connection code or any other possible causes.

Connection string in app.config file:

```html
<connectionStrings>
    <!-- The format of the connection string is "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY" -->
    <!-- For local execution, the value can be set either in this config file or through environment variables -->
    <add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString=" storage connection string" />
    <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString=" storage connection string" />
  <add name="ConnectionStringName" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:[your azure sql server name],1433;Initial Catalog=[sql database name];Integrated Security=False;User Id=[user name];Password=[password];Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Code in Context:

```
 class MyContext: DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString);
        }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

Code in Program:

```
  MyContext context = new MyContext();
  var count = context.Students.ToList().Count();
  Console.WriteLine("rows number:" + count);
```

The firewall in Azure Sql Database:
[image]

Comment: Well, I tried connecting with very basic SQL commands as you suggested. Also fails within WebJob within Azure. It seems that the connection from within webjobs is just not possible. When running locally but with Azure SQL conn string the connection can be successfully established.

Comment: Did you mean you get error when you run web job in Azure? I have tested it , it still works fine(result link:https://image.ibb.co/cD0V3H/webjobsql.png). In my above article link, there are other causes, such as Firewall configuration,Network reconfiguration on the client side and User error. I suggest you could check the possible causes on your side.

Comment: Yep, I get the error, when the job is run in Azure. There must be some firewall issue that I am not aware of. Funny thing is that the web application in which the job ist hosted/run itself can connect to Azure SQL Database. They do share the same outbound IP right?

Comment: OK, it seems that either what runs first: web application or web job can establish a connection. Then the other can't. So when I redeploy web application and job and trigger the job. The connection can be established from the job, but not from the web app. When web app is started first, the job can't access the sql server. Do they share the same pool / resources?

Comment: I think that's not the problem. They are different projects. If I right click my web project>Add>Existing Project as Azure WebJob(link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs), Then I could publish the web project and the related web jobs to Azure together. So they are started at the same time. The job logs and web page all could show the rows number. Maybe you still have something need to check. User name, password or any other.

Comment: Hi, does it work now? If it works, please don't forget to accept it as an answer. Thanks